# Using Scrapy to extract script data with regex

Tags: python, json, parsing, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to extract the content of a script tag on a store locator using Scrapy, but I'm a bit stuck.

Within view source, the script content looks like this:

```
<script>
    var map_locations = [{"col_id":"1","col_postcode":"DN18 5DE","col_latitude":"53.6825556","col_longitude":"-0.438675","col_address1":"9a Market Lane","col_name":"XX","col_website":"https:\/\/branches.XX.co.uk\/barton-upon-humber\/9a-market-lane.html?type=0&stores=DN18+5DE?utm_source=directories&utm_medium=local&utm_campaign=yext&utm_content=1444","col_facebook":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/XXDN185DE\/","col_city":"Barton-Upon-Humber","col_state":"North Lincolnshire","col_yextid":"1444"}...
</script>
```

I copied the xpath and used response.xpath('/html/body/script[1]/text()') to retrieve it within the terminal

Now I want to parse the information in the script into separate columns, which I'll eventually load into csv.

How should I go about parsing that information? Say if I wanted the col_postcode? I've read other posts where people use regex & json.

Comment: So, u looking for an alternate solution other than loading using **regex & json**

Comment: No I'm looking for any solution! It would be great to know how I should approach this

Answer (score 2):

`.*` captures zero or more character's enclosed inside `[]`

```
import re
import json

# response.xpath will return list of 'Selector' Object & calling extract return the extracted string.
for script in response.xpath("/html/body/script[1]/text()").extract():

    search_ = re.search("\[(.*)\]", script)
    # if multiple script tag's exists, find only which matches the condition.
    if search_:
        for doc in json.loads(search_.group()):
            print(doc['col_postcode'])
```

Output

```
DN18 5DE
```

Comment: Hi, when entering this I get:

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Thanks Sushanth, this works!

One question I have is around putting this information back into my Spider with Scrapy. How should this be coded?

import scrapy

class bb_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "stores"
    
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.xx.co.uk/store-locator/'
        ]
    
    def parse(self, response):
        for script in response.xpath("/html/body/script[1]/text()").extract():
            yield {
                'post_code' : stores.xpath
                }

I'm stuck on the yield part! Thanks

Comment: Great, happy to help.